# Check if a User is renaming a file in File Explorer at the Moment C#

Tags: c#, hook, explorer, shell32

I'm programming a C# program which listens for Space pressed in the File Explorer. When space is pressed I create a WPF window which shows the selected File in a WPF Window.

The only problem is, that this file Preview is also called when someone is editing the filename and presses space for a whitespace in the filename.

Is there a way to detect if a user is renaming a file at the moment?

---

Additional Information:

I know that i could listen for F2, but there's also the way to start renaming a file by clicking two times with the left mouse button or by right clicking the file and selecting rename. So this would be no good solution.

Technical Information (if needed):

I use GetForegroundWindow to check if the Window in the foreground is a explorer window. Then i use Hooks to listen for the pressed Keys in the explorer process in foreground.

To get the selected Item i use SHDocVw and Shell32

```
                    Shell32.FolderItems selectedItems = ((Shell32.IShellFolderViewDual2) window.Document).SelectedItems();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to build a windows file preview function similar to the Finder on Mac OS X, whereby pressing space while a file is selected pops up the preview window?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i do/did.

Comment: Explorer already has a preview pane that's toggled with ALT+P. Are you trying to modify the behaviour of the shortcut?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos no I'm not trying to modify the behaviour of the shortcut. I'd created my Preview which Pops up in front of the Explorer. I don't use the preview pane because of the lack of supported Formats and it's not really user friendly

Comment: A thought: how exactly are you hooking into key-presses? Global hooks? Can you share that code? With every keystroke notification, you should be getting the window handle (`HWND` / `IntPtr`) of the control where each keystroke takes place. You would have to check the window class of each such `HWND` and verify that it belongs to a list view (explorer view) and not a text box (file rename box).

Comment: Hey @LeandroTaset, this is the code i used for hooking into key-presses: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ar-SA/88ae8842-5301-4b15-830e-1d6282303508/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-inputs?forum=netfxbcl 
I tried another way to get the active hwnd of a window child. But I can't get the file rename box. do you have an idea how i could get this?

Comment: From the **MSDN** docs for [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990), it seems that you would not be able to get the `HWND` of the focused child control that generated the event while using `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. Perhaps `WH_CALLWNDPROC` or `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` would serve you better in your scenario. However, check this article on **CodeProject**, it should provide some guidance on how to approach the problem using your current code: [Control in Focus in Other Processes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34752/Control-in-Focus-in-Other-Processes).

Comment: Thanks for the Article! I'll have a look at it. If you'd have tips for other approaches I'd be glad if you give them. I can change my code if it'll help me achieve the goal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your file navigation enhancement should not risk interfering with the
>   behaviour currently present in Windows Explorer.

Hence:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Using a new command such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will not get triggered during a file-rename operation plus your application will work using **the standard** baked in Windows OS user-commands *(with a little spice)*.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is an IntelliSense command for us dev's, so its a natural command for people to use for "more info"/"help me out".

<sub>I hope you have a very special File Preview. In the last 2 decades there have been a lot of cases where it has been a PITA not a pleasure :(

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983097

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2257542</sub>

Comment: Hey @Jeremy, i was thinking about this too, but first I wanted to see if it's really not possible with space. Looks like I will Implement Ctrl + Space if there's no other solution. I hope that the File Preview won't be too bad, when I finished it I'll publish the Sourcecode. I'm only having problems with the Preview of Microsoft Office Documents. Best Regards ans thanks for the comment.

Comment: There were a lot of problems - really esoteric - caused by Excel Previews at my last job and with many utilities I have used to do this in the past. Thats why I jumped in, I hope your project is a success (and I will follow your questions on this topic). Since this is your first bounty dont forget to award it by checking the bounty underneath the answer tick mark. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To detect file rename, check for FileSystemWatcher.Changed Event. Here is the example code taken from MSDN. [MSDN FileSystemWatcher Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I have slightly modified code. I have verified the code. It notifies as and when file is renamed.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace FileWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run();
        }

        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public static void Run()
        {
            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

            watcher.Path = @"c:\temp"; //Specify the directory name where file resides

            /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
               the renaming of files or directories. */

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }

        // Define the event handlers. 
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        }

        private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The event `Renamed` occurs after? The way I read it was that the OP wants to trap it when file is being renamed, not after.

Comment: AFAIK, Renamed event occurs only after file is renamed. it does not occur when file is being renamed. please play with the code to confirm the same.

Comment: Hey @Coder, thanks for the try, but the Renamed event only occurs after the file is renamed, so it's not applicable for my problem.